# Search string , if no match then delete line

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I am looking for code to open a text file , then read the text file line by line , if the line in the text file (each line will store approx 5 values) does not contain a certain value e.g "hart" then I wand to remove that line. I am using c# and vs2012 , could anyone show me how to do this ? the file being read from is a csv file. I have no code example here as my current code does not work and I feel givin example will only cause more confusion than asking for someone to show me a clean fresh approach to doing this.

I have added the code I currently have which adds all of the data to a text file however the code I need to figure out is to take these results and filter them

```
     foreach (DataRow dr in this.CalcDataSet.Items)
        {

           foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray)
                {
                    str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
                }


            str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        }


        try
      {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, str.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Error :" + ex.Message);
        }

        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filepath).ToList();
        var acceptedLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
            if (Matches(line))
                acceptedLines.Add(line);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filepath, acceptedLines);
    }

    private bool Matches(string s)
    {
        if (s == cmbClientList.SelectedText.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }

        else  return false;
    }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and we will tell what you are doing wrong

Comment: [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx); [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb342261.aspx); [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ch45axte.aspx); [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dy85x1sa.aspx); [IList.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.ilist.remove.aspx); [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/92e05ft3.aspx)

Comment: We are not here to serve you code on a platter. We can help fix your current code if you post it. That's how the site is supposed to work, regardless of whether you feel it would be "confusing". "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Comment: I've tried using Linq as well as for each loops however i must be doing something wrong as it doesnt return any values , as stated I dont want to use my code , I will add it now though

Comment: @michelle I'm aware of that thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class to open and read the file, and split the values into an array. You can then examine each item on each line to see if it contains the value you want.

If the line contains the value, then write the line to a new file. If it doesn't contain the value, then do not write to the new file.

When you're done, close the input and output files. Then delete the original input file and rename the output file.

You can't easily read and modify a text file in-place.

Another option would be to read using `TextFieldParser` and write to an in-memory stream. At the end, write from the memory stream back to the original file. This will work if the file is small enough to fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This will basically do what you want:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("somefile.csv");
var acceptedLines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
    if (Matches(line))
        acceptedLines.Add(line);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", acceptedLines);


private bool Matches(string s) {
    // Whatever you want, return true to include the line, false to exclude)
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code above to show what it looks like with your code included however I am getting no data in the file

Comment: Step through with the debugger. What does `str.ToString()` evaluate to in your code? Is there really data there like you think? What is the content of `lines`? Does that really contain one string for each line of the file you're reading? After the foreach loop, what does `acceptedLines` have in the list? Anything, nothing? Use your debugger and you'll likely find the problem. Also, you're writing to a file then immediately reading from it - you could probably skip that part and work with the data you already have.

Comment: Note: Try debugging first in the future, you might learn enough to solve your own problem, or at least can post the results of your debugging session here - which might help resolve your issue quicker.

Comment: Why call `ToList` on the result of `ReadAllLines`? It's already an array that you can do a `foreach` on.

Comment: I originally put that in there thinking I could iterate over it an remove the un-needed strings, then remembered you can't modify the list you're iterating over... <shrug>

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
string[] lines  = File.ReadAllLines("yourfile.csv");
List<string> linesToWrite = new List<string>();
int currentCount = 0;

foreach(string s in lines)
{     
  if(s.Contains("YourKeyValue"))
     linesToWrite.Add(s);  
}
File.WriteAllLines("yourfile.csv", linesToWrite );
```